# Running binary from shell script creates core?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am facing an issue when I am running my executable(binary program) from the shell, Its running fine. But when i run that executable from shell script then that executable creates core dump.
For Example: if i run the TEST executable from prompt with arugments like:

```
TEST ARGS
```

It runs fine. But now, I create a script `a.ksh`:

```
#/bin/ksh
cd PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE
Result=Test ARGS
```

and then runs `./a.ksh` and it crash and creates a core dump. 
Any thoughts why running an binary from shell script creating core?

Comment: one more question, Is there any difference running a program on a shell prompt and running the same program from the shell script ?

Comment: The differences between running from a console prompt and a shell script would mainly be in the environment variables, notably the path. Is there a reason you (intend to) run it from ksh? Note that you aren't, the hashbang in the first line is missing the `!`. To be sure, run the script as `/bin/ksh a.ksh`, with a minimal path.

Comment: Oh and do note that in Linux there is no point in doing `cd PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE`, except to set the `$PWD` for the executable. You will still need to add PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE to `$PATH` or run the binary as `./binary`. That is, unless you have made the unholy decision to add `.` to your `$PATH`.

Comment: yes missed ! but what I want to tell is, my script goes to the binary directory and runs the executable. Reason i am running from script is to avoid doing repetitive steps to execute my executable.

Comment: Sure, that's just what scripts are for, so that's only good. Now, I haven't looked at ksh since the late 90's, but `Result=Test ARGS` is not the way to start a script. Please provide the *exact* commands you are running. I think I have a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

Executing this in a shell:

```
$ RESULT=binary args
```

will make the shell attempt to execute `args` in an environment where variable `RESULT` is set to the value `binary`. This will not be what you intended.

Apart from that: the only difference between executing a binary from a console shell and from a shell script invoked from that console shell would be in the values of environment variables.

The cause for the crashing binary could be anything, but a difference in PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH settings would be the most likely. Make sure you `export` these from your console shell, or set them explicitly in the script.

Comment: Ok. what if i replaced the  $(PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE)/binary $ARGS

Comment: ARGS=/home/sprj/input
PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE=/home/program/test
 $(PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE)/binary $ARGS 
but my program still crash..

Comment: what i want to ask is, how does calling a binary from script cause crash? Also I am sure my binary is called by script as I can check the core is created due to my binary. so please suggest what are the factors created difference running a program on a shell prompt and running the same program from the shell script ?

Comment: One more point is, my executable linked with shared library. I added the path of all shared library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable on the shell. DO I need to reset the LD_LIBRARY_PATH again in my shell script to avoid picking shared library from wrong path ?

Comment: I think it is not the calling from a script which crashes the binary. I expect the binary is badly programmed and some environment variable is tripping it up. Notably, the PATH variable, or potentially (but unlikely because why would you touch it?) the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Yes ... Either set it in the environent invoking the script _and_ export it there, or set it in the script itself.

Comment: No, program is fine and providing expected behavior when running from shell prompt.

Comment: But what i understand is, parent process (shell) env variables(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) will be exposed to child process(shell script). So I still need to reset in the shell script again ?

Comment: No, you must export variables if they should be carried over to spawned shells. Try it, nothing beats empirical evidence. In the shell script put `echo "Check: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`.

Comment: I have updated the answer to contain the essence of these comments. If this solves your problem, then please mark as solved, upvote the answer and delete the comments.